# find selected item in wpf xml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

i have this xml code for show list view item in wpf :

```
 <ListView FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  Name="ListViewPost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="504" Margin="1060,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black">
        <ListView.View >
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="عنوان" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and using this code for show id in messsagebox :

```
    private void listView1_MouseClick_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int Id;
        if (ListViewPost.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

        Id = (int)ListViewPost.SelectedItems[0];
        MessageBox.Show(Id.ToString());
    }
```

now i put the break point in this function but it not enter in this . whats the problem ?

Comment: Because you don't have wired up the event. In other words you haven't subscribed your `listView1_MouseClick_1` handler to the respective ListView event. Oh, by the way, a ListView itself does not have a Click event. Bumma! Even if you were managing to do something like that (like with MouseDown/Up events, perhaps), clicking on an item **in** a ListView is NOT the same as clicking the ListView. As it might already occur to you, attempting to handle ListView mouse clicks is probably not going to help reaching your goal (whatever it is).

Comment: Now, start with asking yourself what **precisely** do you want to click on to show the messagebox?

Comment: @elgonzo yes i need this

Comment: @elgonzo please tell me how can i show that id ?

Comment: Your question is not answerable as it currently is. I said in my second comment already what you need to figure out by yourself first, which then will become the starting point for how you will write your code to reach your goal. Please don't ask me to design and write your program for you...

Comment: @elgonzo i need when click on the item it go this function `listView1_MouseClick_1`

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void ListViewPost_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int Id;
    if (ListViewPost.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

    Id = (int)ListViewPost.SelectedItems[0];
    MessageBox.Show(Id.ToString());
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  Name="ListViewPost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="504"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="304" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black"
          SelectionChanged="ListViewPost_SelectionChanged_1">
    <ListView.View >
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="عنوان" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

It will be raised whenever a new item is selected.